# Oracle - Returning same data from different tables based on different conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries: One returns the ID and name of every person/resource assigned as a Team Lead (`NL_TEAM_LEAD`) in the table `ODF_CA_OTHER`, and the other returns the ID and name of every resource with a Team Lead primary role (`PRPRIMARYROLEID = 5112005`) in the table `PRJ_RESOURCES`.

Is there a way to, in a single query, return the ID and name of everyone with a Team Lead primary role in the `PRJ_RESOURCES` table, and also
of everyone assigned as a Team Lead (`NL_TEAM_LEAD`) in the `ODF_CA_OTHER` table (without duplicate names)?

I ask because I need to create this query for a lookup screen that includes all Team Leads and anyone assigned as a Team Lead, but not everyone
assigned as a Team Lead will necessarily have a Team Lead primary role in the resources table.

I frankly have absolutely no idea how to work this in to a single query.

```
-- Resources with Team Lead primary role in PRJ_RESOURCES
SELECT DISTINCT
       SRM.ID AS ID,
       CASE
           WHEN SRM.LAST_NAME IS NULL AND SRM.FIRST_NAME IS NULL AND SRM.MIDDLE_NAME IS NULL THEN ' '
           ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SRM.LAST_NAME, ', '), SRM.FIRST_NAME), NVL(SRM.MIDDLE_NAME, ''))
       END AS NAME
FROM
       SRM_RESOURCES SRM
JOIN
       PRJ_RESOURCES PRJ ON SRM.ID = PRJ.PRID
WHERE
       PRJ.PRPRIMARYROLEID = 5112005;

-- Resources assigned as Team Lead in ODF_CA_OTHER
SELECT DISTINCT
       OTH.NL_TEAM_LEAD AS ID,
       CASE
           WHEN SRM.LAST_NAME IS NULL AND SRM.FIRST_NAME IS NULL AND SRM.MIDDLE_NAME IS NULL THEN ' '
           ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SRM.LAST_NAME, ', '), SRM.FIRST_NAME), NVL(SRM.MIDDLE_NAME, ''))
       END AS NAME
FROM
       ODF_CA_OTHER OTH
JOIN
       SRM_RESOURCES SRM ON OTH.NL_TEAM_LEAD = SRM.ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple `union`, but you are selecting from srm_resources in both cases, so even faster would be to check if id exists in resources with role 5112005 **or** in `odf_ca_other`:

```
select id, nvl(trim(last_name||' '||first_name), ' ') as name
  from srm_resources srm
  where exists (select 1 from prj_resources prj 
                  where prid = srm.id and prprimaryroleid = 5112005)
     or exists (select 1 from odf_ca_other oth 
                  where nl_team_lead = srm.id)
```

Probably you don't need `distinct` in this case. Format name however you want, use your `case` if it works for you.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks